# How do I customize the line in a line chart with PHPPowerpoint/PHPPresentation?

Tags: php, phppowerpoint, phppresentation

How do I customize the lines in the line charts on PHPPowerpoint/PHPPresentation? I can't find anything in there documentation or in the samples to figure this out.

Here's my code:

```
$seriesData = array(
    'Monday' => 12,
    'Tuesday' => 15,
    'Wednesday' => 13,
    'Thursday' => 17,
    'Friday' => 14,
    'Saturday' => 9,
    'Sunday' => 7
);

$lineChart = new Line();
$series = new Series('Downloads', $seriesData);
$series->setShowSeriesName(false);
$series->setShowValue(false);
$series->setShowLeaderLines(false);

$lineChart->addSeries($series);

$shape = $currentSlide->createChartShape();
$shape->setResizeProportional(false)->setHeight(convertIn2Px(2.28))->setWidth(convertIn2Px(5.09))->setOffsetX(convertIn2Px(4.75))->setOffsetY(convertIn2Px(3.9));
$shape->getTitle()->setVisible(false);
$shape->getPlotArea()->setType($lineChart);
$shape->getPlotArea()->getAxisY()->setFormatCode('#,##0');
$shape->getLegend()->setVisible(false);
```

The color of the line graph comes up in blue but I would like to be able to change that color. It also shows the square markers but I would like to make it so that there are no markers on the line.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually in the [develop branch](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation/commit/c25b5537c66f7fdb145cf222537c67714e1504c2#diff-5b63fbb4a824b89cff6871bc7f47da0b).

But you can do this :

```
$oOutline = new \PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Outline();
$oOutline->getFill()->setFillType(Fill::FILL_SOLID);
$oOutline->getFill()->setStartColor(new Color(Color::COLOR_YELLOW));
$oOutline->setWidth(2);

$series->setOutline($oOutline);
```

Comment: is there a way to change the color of the labes (values displayed) of axis X and Y (by default they are black) ?