# Shade the area below line chart - PHPpresenatation

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpoffice, phppresentation

I am making the PPT using PHPpresentation library. In that I have create the line chart, but am unable to color the area below the line.

[image]

this i how it is coming.

but i want something like this

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please, could you go through this link : [How do I customize the line in a line chart with PHPPowerpoint/PHPPresentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34345240/how-do-i-customize-the-line-in-a-line-chart-with-phppowerpoint-phppresentation) ?

I hope that help you to solve your problem. Thanks