# Is there a way to create a line chart with dashed lines with PHPPresentation?

Tags: php, laravel, phppresentation

Is there a way to create a line chart with a dashed line in PhpOffice/PHPPresentation?

I found a solution to set the color for a line chart [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34345240/how-do-i-customize-the-line-in-a-line-chart-with-phppowerpoint-phppresentation):

```
$oOutline = new \PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Style\Outline();
$oOutline->getFill()->setFillType(Fill::FILL_SOLID);
$oOutline->getFill()->setStartColor(new Color(Color::COLOR_YELLOW));
$oOutline->setWidth(2);

$series->setOutline($oOutline);
```

My first attempt was to use the different fill types - but they don't really seem to work. `FILL_NONE` and `FILL_SOLID` are fine, and `FILL_GRADIENT_LINEAR` also works. But `FILL_GRADIENT_PATH` looks exactly like `FILL_GRADIENT_LINEAR`. And the `FILL_PATTERN` constants are all just adding some dots to the line. If I try to edit this line directly in PowerPoint the "no line" option is set.

Next I was looking for a border or line setting but I couldn't fine neither for the outline or the series object.

I'm using the "dev-develop" version of the PhpOffice/PHPPresentation package.

Thanks in advance for your help!